# Setting the authentication when deploying Logic App Custom Connector from ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I am deploying a Logic App Custom Connector via arm template. In the ARM template the type is Microsoft.Web/customApi.

We are also deploying the connector (Microsoft.Web/connections).

The items deploy OK but the Basic Authentication parameters are not linking properly between the customApi and the connection.

[image: Basic auth missing the username and password display labels]

The display names of the params are being reflected in the connection though, and this seems all OK (note the password is supposed to be blank, the test REST API we are using just takes username):

[image: Connection object showing paramters OK]

If we add the display names in to the custom connector, and update the connection, it works. This is what the custom connector looks like after being updated:

[image: Custom API looking OK after manual change]

So we want to get to this point purely from the ARM deployment without manual steps required. Is it possible? The documentation of Microsoft.Web/customApi doesn't give any detail about the connectionParameters you can supply.

ARM snippet for the customApi:

```
 "type": "Microsoft.Web/customApis",
  "name": "[variables('CustomConnectorName')]",
  "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
  "location": "[variables('resourceGroupLocation')]",
  "tags": {
    "Environment": "[variables('environment')]"
  },
  "scale": null,
  "properties": {
    "capabilities": [
      "gateway"
    ],
    "connectionParameters": {
      "username": {
        "type": "string",
        "uiDefinition": {
          "displayName": "ConnectionUsername",              
          "description": "The UserName for this api",
          "tooltip": "Provide the UserName",
          "constraints": {
            "tabIndex": 2,
            "clearText": true,
            "required": "true"
          }
        }
      },
      "password": {
        "type": "string",
        "uiDefinition": {
          "displayName": "ConnectionPassword",              
          "description": "The Password for this api",
          "tooltip": "Provide the Password",
          "constraints": {
            "tabIndex": 3,
            "clearText": false,
            "required": "false"
          }
        }
      },
      "authType": {
        "type": "string",
        "allowedValues": [
          {
            "value": "basic"
          }
        ],
        "uiDefinition": {
          "displayName": "Authentication Type",
          "description": "Authentication type to connect to your API",
          "tooltip": "Authentication type to connect to your API",
          "constraints": {
            "tabIndex": 1,
            "required": "true",
            "allowedValues": [
              {
                "text": "basic",
                "value": "basic"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "gateway": {
        "type": "gatewaySetting",
        "gatewaySettings": {
          "dataSourceType": "CustomConnector",
          "connectionDetails": []
        },
        "uiDefinition": {
          "constraints": {
            "tabIndex": 4,
            "required": "true",
            "capability": [
              "gateway"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
```

ARM snippet for the connection:

```
 "type": "Microsoft.Web/connections",
  "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "name": "MyCustomConnector",
  "properties": {
    "api": {
      "id": "[concat('/subscriptions/',subscription().subscriptionId,'/resourceGroups/',resourceGroup().name,'/providers/Microsoft.Web/customApis/MyCustomConnector')]"
    },
    "displayName": "MyCustomConnector",
    "parameterValues": {
      "username": "[variables('UserName')]",
      "password": "[variables('Password')]",
      "authType": "basic",
      "gateway": {
        "id": "[concat('/subscriptions/',subscription().subscriptionId,'/resourceGroups/',variables('coreResourceGroupName'),'/providers/Microsoft.Web/connectionGateways/',variables('onPremiseGatewayName'))]"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'd be grateful for any suggestions about how we can get the customApi to deploy with the correct parameter names saved to negate the need for the manual step.

Thanks

Comment: I know this is an old post, but I was having a similar issue and got it working.  In the sample ARM template JSON above, I noticed that the username and password "type" is set to "string".  Try setting that to "securestring".  I also noticed that in the ARM snippet for the connection, the user name and password values are set using [variables]... is that right?  My ARM template passes them in as [parameters].

Answer (score 0):

While deploying custom connectors, the connection should be created by the user with their respective `apikey` or whatever auth the connector is using.

So i have modified your template a little bit and it seems to work as expected.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/customApis",
            "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
            "name": "Test",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "properties": {
                "capabilities": [
                    "gateway"
                ],
                "connectionParameters": {
                    "username": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "uiDefinition": {
                            "displayName": "ConnectionUsername",
                            "description": "The UserName for this api",
                            "tooltip": "Provide the UserName",
                            "constraints": {
                                "tabIndex": 2,
                                "clearText": true,
                                "required": "true"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "password": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "uiDefinition": {
                            "displayName": "ConnectionPassword",
                            "description": "The Password for this api",
                            "tooltip": "Provide the Password",
                            "constraints": {
                                "tabIndex": 3,
                                "clearText": false,
                                "required": "false"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "authType": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "allowedValues": [
                            {
                                "value": "basic"
                            }
                        ],
                        "uiDefinition": {
                            "displayName": "Authentication Type",
                            "description": "Authentication type to connect to your API",
                            "tooltip": "Authentication type to connect to your API",
                            "constraints": {
                                "tabIndex": 1,
                                "required": "true",
                                "allowedValues": [
                                    {
                                        "text": "basic",
                                        "value": "basic"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "gateway": {
                        "type": "gatewaySetting",
                        "gatewaySettings": {
                            "dataSourceType": "CustomConnector",
                            "connectionDetails": []
                        },
                        "uiDefinition": {
                            "constraints": {
                                "tabIndex": 4,
                                "required": "true",
                                "capability": [
                                    "gateway"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "backendService": {
                    "serviceUrl": "[concat('https://helloWorld.azurewebsites.net/')]"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Here's how it looks when you try to access this connector from a `LogicApp`

[image]

Notice the change from `[variables('resourceGroupLocation')]` to `[resourceGroup().location]` , it is actually a built in thing in arm template, you can access the location of current resource group that the template is being pointed to.

Also one more thing i have added is the `backendService` which will be pointed to your API URL.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi HariHaran, thanks for your input. We were specifying the backendService URL I just didn't include the whole code because that bit seems to be working OK. What we're trying to achieve though is having no manual steps - we are also deploying the Logic App via ARM and want that to consume the customApi and connection we are creating without anyone having to go in and do anything manually in the portal. We have got it down to one manual step, i.e. confirming the Parameter Labels in the Security screen of the customApi, but It seems odd that this is not possible to automate. Thanks, Matt.

Comment: @matthew-7.7 if you are creating a connection during deployment itself, its better to go with no authentication mechanism

Comment: We have some interfaces where there is no Auth to talk to the other system, and that all works fine. But some of the systems we need to interface to do require Basic Auth.

Answer (score 0):

If you use swagger to model the API, you can define the security requirements as part of the swagger. I used the API-Key method for basic auth, though I think you could probably get the Basic method working as required, I just didnt try it.
https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/authentication/

Here is a example of the swagger property on the Microsoft.Web/customApis JSON type I used in an ARM template (cut down for brevity).

```
        "swagger": {
          "swagger": "2.0",
          "host": "example.sausages.com",
          ...
          "securityDefinitions": {
            "APIKeyHeader": {
              "type": "apiKey",
              "in": "header",
              "name": "Authorization"
            }
          },
          "security": [
            {
              "APIKeyHeader": []
            }
          ],
          "paths": {
            "/sausages": {
              "get": {
                ...
              }
            }
          }
        }
```

When deployed, the security section of the custom connector as well as well defined endpoints available to use.